# Existence and uniqueness of $-\Delta u+u^2=f $

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, nonlinear-analysis

My question is very similar to the one given here: [Existence and uniqueness of $-\Delta u + u^3 =f$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118371/existence-and-uniqueness-of-delta-u-u3-f)

If we consider the equation $-\Delta u+u^2=f$ in 3 dimensions with $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ is there anyhting we can say about possible solutions? The theory of monotone operators, the direct method or any other technique I have seen so far does not cover this case.

Comment: If $f\ge 0$ you can get existence:  the equation $-\Delta u + \max(u,0)^2 = f$ is solvable, this solution is nonnegative, and solves the original equation.

Comment: Can you give me any hints or guide me to any results how to solve your equation?

Comment: $u\mapsto \max(0,u)^2$ is monotone

Comment: @micha, you can use the same method to prove in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118371/existence-and-uniqueness-of-delta-u-u3-f?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @xpaul , I do not think it is possible. In the other thread they can derive a priori estimates involving a term $|u|^4$. This is not possible here since we get $u^3$ and we are not allowed to take absolute values $|u|^3$.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to solve the equation in the above generality. For example take $f=-1$ and Neumann boundary conditions of the form $\partial_n u=0$. Then we can test the above equation by $f$ and get after integration by parts
$$\int_\Omega -u^2=\int_\Omega 1>0$$
which is a contradiction. This suggests that it is important to set further assumptions if one hopes to solve an equation of the above type.

Comment: How about Dirichlet boundary condition?